# Conway's Game of Life Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, conways-game-of-life

I'm learning Nodejs as a complete beginner and starting with the task of recreating Conway's Game of Life. At the moment I simply just want to be able to draw the grid in a browser/console to get started, but i'm having some difficulty doing so.

I've followed a combination of tutorials and this is what i've come up with so far:
main.js

```
var http = require(http);
var InitGrid = require('./InitGrid.js');

http.createServer(function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(console.log(InitGrid.InitGrid()));
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

InitGrid.js

```
function make2DArray(GridWidth, GridHeight){

    let arr = new Array(GridHeight);

    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = new Array(GridWidth);
    }
    return arr;
}

let grid;
let GridWidth = 50;
let GridHeight = 50;

function InitGrid() {

    grid = make2DArray(GridWidth, GridHeight);
    for (let i=0; i < GridWidth; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j < GridHeight; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = floor(random(2));
        }
    }

}
```

When I run the above code by using 'node main.js', I get the following error:

```
assert.js:42
  throw new errors.AssertionError({
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: missing path
    at Module.require (module.js:585:3)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sara\Downloads\gameoflife\javascript-node\GameOfLife\script\main.js:1:74)
    at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

Comment: The stack trace points out that there is a problem with calling `require` in the first line of the file. `require(http)` should be `require('http')`

Comment: I searched on your error and found the duplicate within the first couple of hits. Please do some research before asking a question on Stack Overflow.